# open chrome custom tab in-app rather than in a window

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm running into some issues with ChromeCustomTabs, although it might just be a misunderstanding on my end. I have an app where I have the option to open three links, an instagram page, facebook page, and a twitter page. Now, I chose to use custom tabs since it shares credentials with the system and so I won't have to ask the user to login when hitting these pages.

The problem is that facebook and twitter open in a new window, when I really need to get it to open in app where my menus are still available. Is this possible, or is a webview the only way to get a webpage to open in-app?

If this is the case, is there a way to get the links to open without prompting a user if they'd rather launch in chrome or in the native app?

I would like to avoid having to implement a webview with OAuth calls for easy logins if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the simple-chrome-custom-tabs for my project. It could be download from https://github.com/novoda/simple-chrome-custom-tabs. There are many parameters which could be used to customize the UI. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.